# 4-digit number, where $d_{1000} \lt d_{100} \lt d_{10}\lt d_{1}$

Tags: number-representation

I need to find all 4-digit numbers, where ones-number > tens-number > hundreds-number > thousands-number. 6789 is the highest possible such number and 1234 is the lowest. One solution is to write them all, but it is not an optimal solution.

Writing them all, gave me an answer that there are 26 numbers like these.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Is this Question about the Software Mathematica? If so please complement your Question with Code. Else [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions)  satisfies your needs better.

Comment: It was in my high school test, so computer was not allowed

Comment: This StackExchange site is specifically about a software system called Mathematica. One solution to this problem with it is `With[{digits = Array[c, 4]}, FromDigits[digits] /. Solve[Flatten@{Less@@digits, 1 <= # <= 9 & /@ digits}, digits, Integers]]`.

Comment: Ask on math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
n /. Solve[
  {n == th*1000 + h*100 + t*10 + u, u > t > h > th,
    Thread[0 < {th, h, t, u} < 10]} // Flatten,
  {th, h, t, u, n}, Integers]

(*  {1234, 1235, 1236, 1237, 1238, 1239, 1245, 1246, 1247, 1248, 1249, \
1256, 1257, 1258, 1259, 1267, 1268, 1269, 1278, 1279, 1289, 1345, \
1346, 1347, 1348, 1349, 1356, 1357, 1358, 1359, 1367, 1368, 1369, \
1378, 1379, 1389, 1456, 1457, 1458, 1459, 1467, 1468, 1469, 1478, \
1479, 1489, 1567, 1568, 1569, 1578, 1579, 1589, 1678, 1679, 1689, \
1789, 2345, 2346, 2347, 2348, 2349, 2356, 2357, 2358, 2359, 2367, \
2368, 2369, 2378, 2379, 2389, 2456, 2457, 2458, 2459, 2467, 2468, \
2469, 2478, 2479, 2489, 2567, 2568, 2569, 2578, 2579, 2589, 2678, \
2679, 2689, 2789, 3456, 3457, 3458, 3459, 3467, 3468, 3469, 3478, \
3479, 3489, 3567, 3568, 3569, 3578, 3579, 3589, 3678, 3679, 3689, \
3789, 4567, 4568, 4569, 4578, 4579, 4589, 4678, 4679, 4689, 4789, \
5678, 5679, 5689, 5789, 6789}  *)

Length[%]

(*  126  *)
```

Comment: `FromDigits /@ Select[Tuples[Range[9], {4}], OrderedQ[#] && DuplicateFreeQ[#] &]` gives the same result, but it is perhaps more direct, and a bit faster. (+1)

Comment: @MarcoB - I voted to reopen so that you can post your answer.